# MonoTouch System.EntryPointNotFoundException for a DLL

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to make a DLL with some native code functions that are accessed by my MonoTouch app. I followed the general methodology used by monotouch-bindings, where you:

- make an xcode project and put some native code in it
- build a static library (.a file) with xcodebuild
- run btouch with --link-with to make a .dll file
- add a reference to the .dll file in my MonoTouch app

.. but whenever I try to use these functions in my app, I get System.EntryPointNotFoundException. Here's code for each thing I'm trying to do:

**In the .cpp file:**

```
extern "C" {
   int SomeFunction();
}

int SomeFunction() {
   ...
}
```

**Command line to build the .a file**

```
xcodebuild -project MyStaticLibrary.xcodeproj -target MyStaticLibrary -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Release clean build
```

**The .cs file (NativeBindings.cs) with the bindings**

```
public class MyStaticLibraryBindings
{
    [ DllImport( "__Internal" ) ]   public extern static int SomeFunction();
}
```

**AssemblyInfo.cs for the DLL**

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;

[assembly: LinkWith ("libMyStaticLibrary.a", LinkTarget.Simulator | LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.ArmV7s, IsCxx = true, ForceLoad = true, Frameworks = "", WeakFrameworks = "")]
```

**The command line to build the .dll**

```
btouch -x=NativeBindings.cs AssemblyInfo.cs --out=NativeBindings.dll --link-with=libMyStaticLibrary.a,libMyStaticLibrary.a
```

.. the DLL builds fine, and my app sees the MyStaticLibraryBindings.SomeFunction function during compilation, but at runtime when I call it, I get System.EntryPointNotFoundException.

I have verified that libMyStaticLibrary.a *does* contains SomeFunction:

```
~/build> nm libMyStaticLibrary.a*
00000167 T _SomeFunction
```

Comment: Can you add "-v -v -v" (without the quotes) to the additional mtouch arguments in the project's iOS Build options page and upload the complete build log somewhere (pastebin, gist, etc)?

Comment: Sure: http://pastebin.com/yNi0MPSi

Comment: Do you have a LinkWith attribute in your AssemblyInfo.cs (and exactly how is it)? It doesn't look like Xamarin.iOS extracted the native library from the binding project, which is probably due to something wrong with the LinkWith attribute.

Comment: Yeah, it's in there: http://pastebin.com/rVKwDtr8

Comment: Rolf: What should I see in the build output that lets me know that MonoTouch is properly extracting the native library from the binding project? I don't even see that for other .dlls I'm using that have native libraries (like Facebook.dll).

Comment: One other thing to note: If I go under my MonoTouch project's references and open this DLL, the .a file (libMyStaticLibrary.a) is inside of it under Resources.

Comment: You didn't add "-v -v -v" to the additional mtouch arguments, that will produce a more verbose build output.

Comment: I did add "-v -v -v" to the additional mtouch arguments (opened Project Options, went under Build->iOS Build, and added it to 'additional mtouch arguments'). It doesn't change the output. I'm using the Indie version of MonoTouch.. maybe the Indie version doesn't support verbose mtouch output?

Comment: Ah sorry, I see now you did, I looked in the wrong place in the log. I'm running out of ideas to try: can you upload NativeBindings.dll somewhere I can download and look at it?

Comment: Sure, I can do that, but could you instead tell me some commands to run on it so I can inspect it? It would be helpful for me (and I think a lot of people) to know how to inspect a MonoTouch dll.

Comment: I was going to try to use it in a project, to see where the problem is. If you want to inspect it, just use Reflector (or any other similar tool).

Answer (score 2):

Also, the symbol found in your library is `_SomeFunction` while you're trying to P/Invoke `SomeFunction`. I had some cases where the binding was only possible with the proper prefix

Comment: Good idea, I'll try that. Also, does anyone know how to find out what symbols are in a MonoTouch .dll file? (Like the equivalent of DUMPBIN on Windows). I can use "nm <MyAppExecutableFile>" to see the symbols in the app's executable file, but I don't know how to inspect all the symbols in the dll.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't fix it. I still get "System.EntryPointNotFoundException: _SomeFunction" at runtime when I try to call the function.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem happens on a device, it's because you're building the native library for the simulator only, while you're building the dll for armv7, armv7s and the simulator.
You need to build the native library 3 times, once for each targetted architecture, the lipo them together:

```
lipo -create -output libMyStaticLibrary.a libMyStaticLibrary-armv7.a libMyStaticLibrary-armv7s.a libMyStaticLibrary-simulator.a
```

Comment: Thanks Stephane. In this case, I'm on the simulator, and I'm also using lipo so I've definitely got all architectures together.