# realm in Xamarin, System.EntryPointNotfoundException when trying to use realm

Tags: realm

I have installed `realm` in a Xamarin app and when I try to use an object (count, write, etc) it gives me a `System.EntryPointNotFoundException`.

Below code:

```
_realm = Realm.GetInstance();
_realm.Write(() =>
            {
                var myConfig = _realm.CreateObject<Config>();
                myConfig.Email = "";
                myConfig.User = "";
            });
```

> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: shared_realm_begin_transaction
>     at at (wrapper managed-to-native) Realms.NativeSharedRealm:begin_transaction (Realms.SharedRealmHandle)
>     at Realms.Transaction..ctor (Realms.SharedRealmHandle sharedRealmHandle) [0x0000d] in :0
>     at Realms.Realm.BeginWrite () [0x00000] in :0
>     at Realms.Realm.Write (System.Action action) [0x00000] in :0
>     at rasoApp.ConfigViewModel..ctor () [0x00025] in /Users/luis/Projects/rasoApp/rasoApp/viewModels/ConfigViewModel.cs:22
>     at rasoApp.ConfigPage.SetBinding (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty targetProperty, Xamarin.Forms.BindingBase binding) [0x0000e] in /Users/luis/Projects/rasoApp/rasoApp/views/ConfigPage.xaml.cs:13
>     at rasoApp.HomePage.btnOpenConfig (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00007] in /Users/luis/Projects/rasoApp/rasoApp/views/HomePage.xaml.cs:18
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Button.Xamarin.Forms.IButtonController.SendClicked () [0x00020] in :0
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ButtonRenderer.OnButtonTouchUpInside (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs) [0x0000e] in :0
>     at UIKit.UIControlEventProxy.Activated () [0x00007] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3412/3cf8aaed/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIControl.cs:38
>     at at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
>     at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, IntPtr principal, IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3412/3cf8aaed/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79
>     at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3412/3cf8aaed/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
>     at rasoApp.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/luis/Projects/rasoApp/iOS/Main.cs:17

Comment: See Update 2016-07-11 for more questions especially Full LInking

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations on an *interesting* problem!

I have seen a similar error but **only** in recent work I was doing refining code generation, when I generated bad IL code. We have no previous issues recorded nor any discussions of `EntryPointNotFoundException` messages that I can find.

If you try building one of our examples from the [Realm source download](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet), such as `QuickJournal` does that work?

If you can send a full project demonstrating the problem to help@realm.io that is probably the fastest way to work out what is happening.

**Update 2016-07-11**
Looking at [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210123/monotouch-system-entrypointnotfoundexception-for-a-dll) made me think of a few more things to try:

- Does this happen on all platforms?

  ### - Do you have Full Linking enabled in Xamarin studio?

**Earlier Suggestions**

Does your app have a PCL containing that logic?

Did you **also** install the Realm NuGet into the main application (IOS or Android) projects? That is a necessary step. The main Realm libraries are only included with the platform-specific dlls which NuGet adds to IOS or Android projects.

Comment: Andy, I installed Realm in all the projects (PCL, ANDROID, IOS), furthermore, If I do this:

var configEnum = _realm.All<Config>();

it doesn't gives me an exception, so the package is installed, I believe..

Comment: Updated answer above requesting more details.

Comment: Andy, I had problems with IOS because of versions of Xamarin and OSX, I had to stablish LInker behaviour to LInk frameworks SDKs only, did you mean that?

Comment: Yes, we support Link Framework SDKs only but may have problems with Link All.

Comment: I get the same exception: `System.EntryPointNotfoundException schema_create`, just trying to make Realm work for the first time. `var session = Realm.GetInstance ().All<Session> ().First ();` The linker behavior is set to "Link Frameworks SDKs only". I'll try to compile an example project then.

Comment: Well, QuickJournal is running normally :)