# Xamarin forms Realm Platform user login Exception on iOS only

Tags: c#, ios, database, xamarin.forms, realm

I downloaded the QuickJournal sample app. Set up my account and added a user in Realm Cloud.
After that, I added this simple code to login the user.

```
Uri authURL = new Uri("$$InstanceUrlHere");
Credentials credentials = Credentials.UsernamePassword(“Ali”, “123”, createUser: false);
try
{
    //trying to login using realm default authticaion: username and password
    var user = await User.LoginAsync(credentials, authURL);
    await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(“Confirmation”, "User Identitiy from Realm Login: " + user.Identity, “Ok”);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(“Error”, “Error while Trying to login”, “Ok”);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error while Trying to login: " + ex);
}
```

Code is working fine on Android Emulator. But, on iOS, I am getting the following error on the LoginAsync step:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for ‘Realms.Sync.SharedRealmHandleExtensions’ threw an exception. —> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: realm_install_syncsession_callbacks
at (wrapper managed-to-native) Realms.Sync.SharedRealmHandleExtensions+NativeMethods.install_syncsession_callbacks(Realms.Sync.SharedRealmHandleExtensions/NativeMethods/RefreshAccessTokenCallbackDelegate,Realms.Sync.SharedRealmHandleExtensions/NativeMethods/SessionErrorCallback,Realms.Sync.SharedRealmHandleExtensions/NativeMethods/SessionProgressCallback,Realms.Sync.SharedRealmHandleExtensions/NativeMethods/SessionWaitCallback)
at Realms.Sync.SharedRealmHandleExtensions…cctor () [0x0004e] in :0
```

I found this similar question but it's old and not helping my case:

[realm in Xamarin, System.EntryPointNotfoundException when trying to use realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279243/realm-in-xamarin-system-entrypointnotfoundexception-when-trying-to-use-realm)

Comment: Have you tried to use real device to deploy that?

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT
For some reason , after updating Xamarin forms ,Realm, Fody, and other libraries, it's working fine now.

Comment: OK, glad you have solved it.

Comment: I am currently getting a crash if I debug the app and step into code 
2018-05-28 11:15:48.815 QuickJournal.iOS[6014:82756] error: * Assertion at /Users/builder/data/lanes/5944/408d3574/source/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mono/mini/debugger-agent.c:4831, condition `array->len == 1' not met

Comment: The strange thing is that, crash never happen when I run the code without stepping

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT Thanks for the support

Comment: This is an other issue, you may open a new thread and declare more details about it.